# AKS maxPods update without recreating the cluster

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

I have an AKS with
"name": "agentpool1",

```
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "orchestratorVersion": "1.17.8",
    "count": 3,
    "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
    "maxPods": 30,
    "osType": "Linux",
    "osDiskType": "Ephemeral",
    "osDiskSizeGB": 64
```

Is it possible to change the "maxPods": 30 to "maxPods": 100 without recreating the cluster. if so appreciate if you can answer how.

[Managed clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters)

Getting this error when I try

```
The template deployment 'sbstest-deployment' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '70443a7c-8411-49ba-b278-e4fgjhgh'. See inner errors for details.
Details:
PropertyChangeNotAllowed: Provisioning of resource(s) for container service sbstest-aks in resource group sbstest failed. Message: {
  "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
  "message": "Changing property 'agentPoolProfile.kubernetesConfig.kubeletConfig.maxPods' is not allowed.",
  "target": "agentPoolProfile.kubernetesConfig.kubeletConfig.maxPods"
 }. Details: 
Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Comment: Do you consider only ARM templates or also Azure CLI to change value of maxPods?

Comment: We have pipeline hence arm. But if it is possible to update it using azure CLI commands then maybe something I can propose

Comment: Could this work for you?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni#configure-maximum---existing-clusters

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to change the "maxPods": 30 to "maxPods": 100 without recreating the cluster?

When you create a new AKS cluster, you automatically create a system node pool, but you can't change node taints through the CLI after the node pool is created.

However, as an alternative method, you can [create a new node pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools#add-a-dedicated-system-node-pool-to-an-existing-aks-cluster) with the desired `maxPods` to your AKS cluster.

**Note that you need to set the `mode` of the pool as `System`.**

And then, [delete the the old node pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools#delete-a-node-pool).

```
az aks nodepool delete -g myResourceGroup --cluster-name myAKSCluster --name mynodepool --no-wait
```

Besides, I have found another method in [github](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/542#issuecomment-580495962). You can check both methods to see which one works better for you.